# Decrypt byte data in javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, compression, gzip

I have a project where i used gzip in .cs file to zip the data and get it in html page.
Here is my code for gzip.

```
public byte[] CustomerList()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select CustomerID from CustomerMaster", con);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return CompressData(ds);
    }
    public byte[] CompressData(DataSet ds)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(gzip, ds);
                gzip.Close();
            }

            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

i successfully received the data from html page using ajax function. Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Service1.svc/CustomerList",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        processdata: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data.CustomerListResult);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                });



</script>
```

I received the data in byte format. Now i want to decrypt the byte-data to get the original data. Here i got stuck. Please help me how to decrypt the byte to get the original data.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to not compress the data and, instead, enable compression on the web server. If you must pre-compress the data, then you'll need to decompress it at the other end (this will not be the quickest thing in the world). I don't know C#, but it looks like you're using standard gzip; so you'll have to either write your own gzip library or find one that's already been made before. A quick Google found [this](https://github.com/beatgammit/gzip-js): it's for node.js, but you could probably port it for use in a browser.

**tl;dr** Get your web server to compress the data, rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: If you *do* go down the "let's use JavaScript to decompress this" route of madness, also bear in mind that browser JS doesn't deal particularly well with raw byte sequences/streams. You might have more success if you change your C# so that it outputs text encoded data (e.g., BASE64, etc.), which your JS would then have to decode then decompress... Good luck with that!